# JS hide Frame from different frameset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frameset

I need to hide a frame by clicking on  tag from a different frameset. (tha page has more frames)
I tried:

```
 $("#azSUBMIT").click(function(){
        $("frame[name='frameHidden']").hide();
    });
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d79zfstf/4/)

Comment: Frames are deprecated and it's use is not recommended by W3C recommendations. Consider the option of change your development if it's possible.

Comment: Thanks but I can not. I am editing a third part page

Comment: If you inspect the DOM in jsfiddle there is no frame tag.

Comment: Bardo's comment is unhelpful. What he means is `frame` is deprecated, but `iframe` is still used widely today. Many pages on the web use third party applications that run inside `iframe`s. With that consideration, maybe you can change your site to not use frames, but use an `iframe` only when you need to work with other sites/applications. Your likely to not find a quick answer on here *because* `frame`'s deprecation means not many people will know the answer.